# Plot problems in Python using pyplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot a graph using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
gr = nx.Graph() 
gr.add_nodes_from(users,bipertite=0)
gr.add_nodes_from(locations,bipertite=0)
gr.add_edges_from(c)
nx.draw(gr)
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])
plt.show()
```

But when the graph is drawn it shows the graph drawn from `gr = nx.Graph()`.
I tried `gr.clear()` but does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try plt.clf().

Networkx uses the pyplot library to plot graphs, so you need to use the pyplot clear function, plt.clf() (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf).

Comment: I tried but it still plot a graph from the nodes of gr (nx.Graph)